# CSV as a signle line string with newlines

Tags: javascript, csv

I have an existing service to create files from strings and zip them up. It currently takes takes JSON as a string as such:

`data: ${ JSON.stringify(data) }`

which works.  However I want to in the came way express that data as a csv.

assume the data is:

`json
[
  {
    "test1": "1",
    "test2": "2",
    "test3": "3",
  },
  {
    "test1": "1",
    "test2": "2",
    "test3": "3",
  },
]`

I have found many good node json to csv libraries, I ended up using `json2csv` and have found that I can successfully create a csv file for one line of data, but not two as follows.

```
// works (header row)
const test = "\"test1\",\"test2\",\"test3\""; 
const csvStr = `data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8, ${ test }`;

// fails (header row + 1 data row)
const test = "\"test1\",\"test2\",\"test3\"\n\"test1\",\"test2\",\"test3\""; 
const csvStr = `data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8, ${ test }`;
```

Based on these tests I believe the issue is with how the newline / carriage return is being used.  If this is even possible.  Anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?  If it's possible to express a CSV file on a single line with line breaks?

Comment: Use papaparse.js

Comment: I orignally tried papaparse,  and that took care of the json to csv part,  but no the encoding as a string part.